# VBA connecting to local SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba

I have SQL Server 2008 installed on my PC and I'm writing VBA code to populate a table on that database. I was able to stitch together the below code from various online sources:

```
Sub connect()
Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim strConn As String
Dim strSRV As String
Dim strDB As String
Dim sql_login As String
Dim sql_pass As String

    'Create the connection string
    strSRV = ".\SQLEXPRESS"
    strDB = "backend"
    sql_login = "asd"
    sql_pass = "asd"

    strConn = "Provider=SQLNCLI10" & _
              "Server=" & strSRV & ";" & _
              "Database=" & strDB & ";" & _
              "Uid=" & sql_login & ";" & _
              "Pwd=" & sql_pass & ";"


    'Create the Connection and Recordset objects
    Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

    ' Open the connection and execute
    conn.Open strConn
    Set rs = conn.Execute("SELECT * FROM *;")

    'Check we have data
    If Not rs.EOF Then
        'Transfer result
        Sheets(1).Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rs

    'Close Recordset
    rs.Close

    Else
        MsgBox "Error: No records returned.", vbCritical
    End If

    'Clean up
    If CBool(conn.State And adStateopen) Then conn.Close
    Set conn = Nothing
    Set rs = Nothing
End Sub
```

Currently I'm getting an error:

> Provider cannot be found

From online research I found that it can be due to ODBC config, so I went to ODBC Data Source Admin. There were 3 User Data Sources defined: dBASE Files, Excel Files and MS Access Database. I added a third one for SQL Server Native Client 10.0.

I was not able to find the answer at `connectionstrings.com` which seems to be a popular reference. What's the reason I'm getting the error? and how can I fix it in general? At one point my VBA will point to a remote server, so I don't want the solution to be a local workaround.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like your strConn is missing a semicolon...try this and see if anything is different:-

```
 strConn = "Provider=SQLNCLI10;" & _
              "Server=" & strSRV & ";" & _
              "Database=" & strDB & ";" & _
              "Uid=" & sql_login & ";" & _
              "Pwd=" & sql_pass & ";"
```

Comment: Worked! Would you know some documentation I could go over to better understand this? For example I have no idea why we're using `SQLNLCI0` opposed to several others I came across.

Comment: I get confused at connection strings too.  You just have to keep on researching - if you're stuck you can always ask more questions on SO!  Glad it worked for you though.

Comment: @newdimension SQLNCLI10 is an OLE provider that gets installed with SQL server. I usually avoid using it in VBA because it has to be installed separately. SQLOLEDB comes with Windows and it seems to work just as well, but the format of the rest of the string is different. http://www.connectionstrings.com/microsoft-ole-db-provider-for-sql-server-sqloledb/

Comment: also you should use Provider=SQLOLEDB.1 instead of SQLOLEDB as suggested in that link. I think I ran into some problems with parameterized queries when not including the .1 (which apparently uses an old version of the driver)